Is it practical in real life to drill magnetic screws into someone's skull in order to wear a wig?
In the first episode of Monsters The Lyle and Erik Menendez Story (2024), Lyle has a heated argument with his parents over his intention to get married at 20 years old.
Eventually, this argument turns ugly. Lyle's mother goes over to him and pulls off his wig, which is attached to four magnetic screws which have been drilled into his skull.
I am wondering if this is practical in real life. Did people indeed have this done in the 1980s? I did a bit search online, and there was no such a service available.

I don't know about wigs but a surgical procedure is there involving drilling of skulls called trepanation.

tl;dr:

such a system existed, briefly.

the guy behind it went to prison for a while, so the idea faded away, though other ideas still exist (subdermal discs instead of screws).

Menendez brother did not have this procedure


not properly researched, so although probably not the correct answer, it is of interest:

https://forensicfilesnow.com/index.php/tag/snap-on-toupee/
https://www.deseret.com/1996/11/28/19279332/for-cosmetic-surgeon-replacing-hair-s-a-snap/
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-Alternative-Attachment-System-for-Hair-Pignataro-Schaaf/fa9b0f15b0a394724d38c8b4d080b6b16b7672f3

...reaches under his hair and - pop! pop! pop! pop! - in a matter of seconds, holds most of his thick, brown locks in the palm of his hand.
All that remains atop his scalp are four gold snaps embedded deep in the bone of his skull. They keep what he calls his "prosthetic hair" in place.
A cosmetic surgeon, Pignataro has been selling his extreme method of hair replacement since he became his own test case four years ago. About 100 other men, from as far away as Seattle, have undergone the procedure since in his suburban Buffalo operating room.


ugh...
edit:
after a brief search, although interesting, it seems the Menendez brother had his glued on, and not as presented in the show.

link - same question in reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/MenendezBrothers/comments/1fmozua/lyle_menendezs_toupee/


I’ll stay bald, thank you

I just know id forget to mention it to TSA staff or those sticking me in the MRI... Plus, ouch, what a headache. Also, never fall asleep with kids and fridge magnets around..

They usually uses transdermal implants these days.  Way less invasive than going into the bone.

Lyle had his wig glued on? He had to de-glue and re-glue every day?

@YuZhang according to other comments he was actually denied his glue whilst in prison, so he went about shaving all his hair off and stayed bald.

@MackM do you have any sources on transdermal implants being used for magnets?

@YuZhang the glue is typically waterproof and can last several days or weeks depending on the type of glue.

You can find wig glue online; many products advertise a "hold time" of weeks. Detailed comparison here. I assume if you're going to bed with a lady, you may not want to remove the wig at bedtime.

@blobbymcblobby Only the first time. :)

@ave I don't really have anything easy to share digitally, mostly people I've met.  Lots of jewelry.  I saw one lady wearing a chain mail veil attached by 4 magnets to transdermal piercings above her eyebrows, it was pretty cool.  Just looking around online I'm having trouble finding something to search that doesn't flood the results with sub-dermal magnet stuff.  It looks like NorthSense might use transdermal attachments?  I am not sure.

A friend of mine, who started going bald in his teens, had a hairpiece like that. I don’t know if they were screwed to the skull, but he had snaps attached to his scalp. One day, he did a flip into the local pool and ripped two of the front snaps loose and the toupee was flapped back and he had two bleeding holes at his hairline.
